# Call Sub if there is a change in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, call

I want to call a Sub, if there is change in a certain cell. With the following code, this works as lang as there is something in the cell.

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target = Range("A1") Or Target = Range("A2") Then Call "Name of Sub"
 End Sub`

However, if there is nothing in the cell "A1" or "A2", I get a Problem. Anyone an idea, how to solve that?

Comment: It works on a change so if you delete something that is in those cells it will run (even though it is now blank) and vice versa if you add something to the blank cell. If it remains blank there is no change to trigger the event.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a design pattern for [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) already:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing) Or (Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing) Then
        Debug.Print "HERE"
    End If
End Sub
```

The intersect checks whether any of the cells in `Target` is `A1` or `A2`.